# Retrieving Css Rules via AngleSharp

Tags: c#, css, anglesharp

I'm trying to get css @page rules from an AngleSharp parsed html file. It's interesting because I can get the Rules property when I am [debugging the stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGdja.png) but not when I try accessing it when writing code. Am I missing a nuget package?

```
string input = "<style type=\"text/css\">body,p,div {font-family:Times; font-size:10pt; text-align:justify;}" + "@page :first { size: letter portrait; margin-top:1in; margin-right: .5in; margin-bottom: .5in; margin-left:1in;}" + "@page :last { size: letter portrait; margin-top:200in; margin-right: 50in; margin-bottom: 50in; margin-left:1in;" + "</style>";

var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss();
var ctx = BrowsingContext.New(config);

IDocument document = await ctx.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(input));

IStyleSheet sheet = document.GetStyleSheets().First();
```

I'm unable to access Rules property when [writing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQCd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert to an `ICssStyleSheet`. An `IStyleSheet` has no CSS rules. Only an `ICssStyleSheet` has.

```
var sheet = document.GetStyleSheets().OfType<ICssStyleSheet>().First();
```

Note that by specification there are multiple possible kinds of stylesheets. Practically, its only CSS.